# Secure Object Permissions for Guest Users (Security Alert) May 2020

Tags: administration, security-review, pre-release, release-notes

I am a little bit confused with this security alert that will take place in May of 2020.

Within the sandbox they only list 3 objects, where this update will be affected
Contracts, Order, and SurveyResponse (as highlight below)
[image]

However, in the official salesforce release notes (https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_networks_secure_perms_guests.htm) they actually talks about custom objects too (Orders, Contracts, and custom objects)
[image]

Is there a typo in one of them? and which one?

Comment: Did you try and spin up a new org, enable the critical update, and see if the permissions could be assigned to custom objects?

Comment: Well I am a bit confused with that to, as it says it is a security upgrade, I cant see anything on critical updates. The get started also doesnt mentioned to activate it just says For each community or portal with guest access, edit the guest user profile:  Update object permissions on standard and custom objects to follow Salesforce best practices Pro Tip: If a guest user doesn’t need access to the object, remove all object permissions, Modify All Data, and View All Data access.) But anyway you cant have "view all" and "modify all" permission on standard object for guest users anyway

Comment: I've opened a case with Salesforce about this. Will let you know if I hear back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a case with Salesforce about this. They informed me that 'the Security Alert in Setup is subject to change' and that 'the official statement is in the release notes'. The [release notes for Spring '20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_networks_secure_perms_guests.htm) state:

> In all guest user profiles created in Summer ’20 and above, the admin
>   can no longer give guests access the following permissions on the
>   following objects: updates on **Survey Responses**, update or delete on
>   **Orders**, **Contracts**, and **custom objects**.
>
> **When:** This change is taking place in Summer ‘20, but we want you to
>   have time to assess the effect of this change in your org.